# Print area lost when opening Excel file from C++

Tags: c++, excel

I'm experiencing a very strange error - the print area is lost when opening an Excel template from C++.

I have an Excel template file - "MyFile.xltx". In one of the sheets in the file, I've set a print area. If I open the file by double clicking on it in Explorer, everything works as expected - the print area is still there. But if I open the file in my C++ code, the print area is removed. Everything else looks file, the only thing missing is the print area.

You have the code below - as barebone as possible. I'm using the automatically generated Excel helpers in my program - e.g. the "Open" call is mapped to a simple "InvokeHelper(0x2aa, ..." call. (I've tried using the newer 0x783 call - with two extra arguments - but I get the same result.)

I'm running Microsoft Office 2010 and Visual Studio 2010.

I'm no COM expert, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. But this is a simple open, so I think this is a strange error... I'd be most grateful for any help! :-)

/Anders from Sweden

```
//
// get CLSID for Excel
//

CLSID clsid;
if (FAILED (CLSIDFromProgID (L"Excel.Application", &clsid))) {
    MessageBox ((HWND) NULL, "Can't find Excel", "", MB_OK);
    return;
}

//
// attach to a running Excel application - or start one if there is no
// running instance
//

_Application oExcelApp; 

IUnknown *pUnk;
if (FAILED (GetActiveObject (clsid, NULL, (IUnknown **) &pUnk))) {
    if (!oExcelApp.CreateDispatch (clsid)) {
        MessageBox ((HWND) NULL, "Can't start Excel", "", MB_OK);
        return;
    }
}
else {
    LPDISPATCH lpDisp = NULL;
    pUnk->QueryInterface (IID_IDispatch, (void **) &lpDisp);
    pUnk->Release();
    oExcelApp.AttachDispatch (lpDisp);
}

//
// call the Open method for the Workbooks collection - to open the file
//

COleVariant vOpt ((long) DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);

Workbooks oBooks = oExcelApp.GetWorkbooks ();
_Workbook oExcel = oBooks.Open ("MyFile.xltx", vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt,
  vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt);

//
// make the Excel workbook visible
//

oExcelApp.SetUserControl (TRUE);
oExcelApp.SetVisible (TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your question when i was investigating a similar problem with my excel. when i opened the files with excel the print area worked fine, but if i accessed them trough a (AutoIt) script the files where missing the print area

after a lot of search work i found out that to problem was that i was using a Dutch version of excel instead of the English, this meant that the print area (which is a Defined cell range, found under (formulas > Name Manger) called Print_area) was not recognized as such, but instead the excel was looking for the cell range: "Afdrukbereik" (dutch for printarea).

may you can have a look in your file when it is opened from C++ to see if print_area is set and if you recreate the print area which defined name is created for that...

i hope i make some sense and that it can help you.

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I needed. It was the same problem you had encountered - somehow, the localized name of the Print_Area name is lost when opening an XLTX file. And then the Swedish Excel doesn't recognize the name as a print area. A bug in Excel, but now that we know the reason, we can perhaps find a workaround. A big THANK YOU for taking the time to answer! :-)

Comment: i had the same problem with a dutch version of excel and com/ole from within delphi. Worked fine when opening from explorer / excel itselve did not work when opening using com / ole.

My solution was to loop through the excellapp.names collection looking for named ranges with the name "Print_area" extract the sheet and range then loop through the sheets of the active workbook and if i came across the sheet referenced in the "Print_area" named range i set the extracted range from "Print_area" to sheet.pagesetup.printarea.

I'm doing this after the workbooks.open command